# Starting with Java EE6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have just started reading about Java EE6 and I have bought the book "EJB 3 in Action" and "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1". I have not the last book yet and just started chapter 2 in the first book, but I can't see much "frontside" development in these books. Can anyone recommend any tutorials or books that I could read together with these so that I can code some HTML etc that uses EJB? I am new to this kind of development but I heard of JSP and JSF.

Answer (score 2):

For Java EE 6 *front side* development using the technologies inside the stack (instead of bringing in e.g. Spring), you should look into using JSF 2.0.

I would suggest the same book as I used for this:

http://horstmann.com/corejsf/

You might also find the articles in this series interesting:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=JSF+2+fu

starting with http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu1/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The JBoss AS 7 documentation contains step-by-step instructions for developing a simple applications using JSF, EE6, JBoss and Eclipse.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Developing+Applications+Guide

Answer (score 1):

[Check this for creating an Enterprise Application with EJB 3.1](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html#Exercise_1and%20JSF.)

[EJB 3.1 tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ejb-31-%E2%80%93-ejb-new-and-improved-)